# How to download WordPress files from Google Cloud Platform

Tags: wordpress, google-cloud-platform, backup, cloud-hosting

I have a client's website build on WordPress and hosted on Google cloud host. Now I want to backup it before developing the new website for him. Is there any way to download all files as a zip or any other option?

Comment: Use a plugin such as `All-in-One WP Migration`. I use this to backup my WordPress site and to migrate it to different domain names for testing (I have production and development versions). WordPress comprises files, themes, plugins and MySQL database tables. One tip. The plugins do not backup your SSL certificate files or custom Apache configurations.

Comment: Another tip. If this site is hosted on Google Compute Engine, create a snapshot of the instance's disk drives. This can be used later to recover a site or access a file you suddenly need.

Answer (score 1):

You have several ways. Two of them already suggested by [@John Hanley](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8016720/john-hanley);

1. If you have access to the GCP console you can [create a disk snapshot](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/create-snapshots) of a VM running Wordpress (most convinient and easy - also reliable).
2. If you just have SSH access to the VM - just manually backup all the files & database
3. Use one of many available back-up/migration plugins.